# Use draggable jQuery method and hide the scrollbar on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I did a div with a big width (i.e.3000px) and I hide it with a parent div with `overflow:scroll`, beacuse with a `overflow:hidden` I can't scroll to right/left.

So the best answer need to do a div that I can scroll to left/right (preferably with a draggable method) not having the scrollbar.

My code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="contents-home-container">
  <div class="contents-home-container-inner">

      <div class="contents-home">
      <!-- X7 <contents-home divs> -->
      </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-home-conteiner {

  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 75vh;

 }

.contents-home-container-inner {

 width: 2600px;
 margin-left: 250px;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;

}

.contents-home {

 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 width: 13%;
 height: 100%;

}
```

**jQuery**

I tried with the `.draggable` method but the console output an error that display ".draggable is not a function" (something like this, but I copy/paste the basically function from the jQuery documentation..). I'm using WordPress.

[image: header]

Answer (score 0):

> .draggable is not a function

means the draggable js is not called before the code.

include jquery and jqueryUI in your code.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have the ui-kit and now I have the same error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

Comment: @SashaChirico Have you included jquery ui in it or show the js and html code

Comment: I have added your script on the header.php on <header></header>, to use the ui kit, but still display the error

Comment: look in the question above